# Query outside while loop, for using inside loop, does'nt work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, while-loop

I have the following **working** code

```
$notchDetails = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM notches WHERE projectid = ".$projectid." LIMIT ".$offset.", ".$limit."");
// i want $query here //
$outp3 = "[";
if (mysqli_num_rows($notchDetails) > 0) {
  while($notch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($notchDetails)) {

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "DESCRIBE $table");

    $count = count($notch);
    $allnotches[] = $notch["notchid"]; // $allnotches is needed further in script //
    if ($outp3 != "[") {$outp3 .= ",";}

    $outp3 .= "{";

    $x = 1;
    while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $field = $rs["Field"];
        $outp3 .= '"'.$field.'":"'.$notch[$field].'"';
        if ($x != $count) { $outp3 .= ","; } 
        $x++;
    }   

    $outp3 .= "}";
  }
}
$outp3 .="]";
```

*(Don't look at the var name notch, could'nt find a better translation than notch. Its complicated ;-) )*

**Problem explained:**

When i place `$query = mysqli_query...`

outside the while loop (just under `$notchDetails = mysqli_query...`),

it only gives 1 result and the rest is left empty in: `while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { //result// }`

Af far as i can see, it should work with the $query above the loop. But i don't understand why it is'nt.

Can someone explain me why this does'nt work?

*P.s. The reason for placing it outside the loop is performance/speed*

Comment: Am I taking you right and you are creating JSON structure manually?

Comment: That's right. I need to put multiple json inside 1 text document (using serialize and then a encryption over that). Do you have a better solution?

Comment: Hmm i am aware of json_encode, but choose for manually because of a reason i dont know anymore. But i can give it a try

Comment: But, i am still wondering why my code doen'st work :P

Comment: To be frank, I am still wondering what does this code do, and what for. Where does $table come from, why can't you move not only query but whole $table business outside the loop, and many other questions.

Comment: Oh forgot to change $table. But $table = "notches"; Its declared in my script so thats not the problem

Comment: How could i place all outside the loop? Then tje json string is out of format

Comment: @YourCommonSense i changed all and use json_encode now. Won't say thats its faster then manual actually with the exact same result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_assoc` is iterating through `mysqli_result`. When you have ended the iterating, you are not able to iterate it again. You can create a new query and iterate it.

So, when you put `$query = mysqli_query($conn, "DESCRIBE $table");` outside the `while` loop, you are not creating a new query to iterate, so, after first iterating is completed, `mysqli_fetch_assoc` is not returning anything because you have no new queries, and old query is already iterated.

I would do something like:

```
$fields = [];

$table_structure = mysqli_query($conn, "DESCRIBE `notches`");
while ($row = $table_structure->fetch_assoc()) {
    $fields[] = $row['Field'];
}

$notch_details = mysqli_prepare(
    $conn,
    'SELECT * FROM `notches` WHERE `projectid` = ? LIMIT ?, ?'
);
$notch_details->bind_param('iii', $projectid, $offset, $limit);
$notch_details->execute();
$notch_details = $notch_details->get_result();

$result = [];

while($notch = $notch_details->fetch_assoc()) {
    $values = [];

    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $values[$field] = $notch[$field];
    }

    $result[] = $values;
}

$result = json_encode($result);
```

As you can see, I have prepared a list of `$fields` once, and I use it later just as a list of fields, no need to query table description again and again.

**Edit:** Also, when you querying a database and fetching data as an associative array, you need no knowledge about table fields because you already have fields names in your result:

```
$notch_details = mysqli_prepare(
    $conn,
    'SELECT * FROM `notches` WHERE `projectid` = ? LIMIT ?, ?'
);
$notch_details->bind_param('iii', $projectid, $offset, $limit);
$notch_details->execute();
$notch_details = $notch_details->get_result();

$result = json_encode($notch_details->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```

You will have the same result here without querying a table structure.

Comment: Thanks. Good explaination!

Comment: @RamonBakker. You are welcome. I also hope this answer will be useful not only as an answer for your question, but also as an example of prepared statements which are safer than direct inserting variables into a query.

Comment: I am aware of SQL Injection and i know how to prevent it.

Comment: I'm not using prepared statements. But bin2hex the variable and use UNHEX('$var') in the query.

Comment: @RamonBakker, also, I've just edited my answer. As I understand, you want to get JSON string as a result. There is a [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function is exists in PHP which does exactly you want. No need to build it manually.

Comment: I think `UNHEX` will not help you when `$projectid = bin2hex('1; SELECT * FROM users --'`. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php and see Zaffy's answer

Comment: And it will actually help. Also Hex attacks are not possible ;)

Comment: `SELECT * FROM notches WHERE projectid = UNHEX('$projectid')`. Try inject yourself ;)

Comment: Ah, now I understand the idea. Thank you for a link. I like the prepared statements because of their universality, but UNHEX also can be useful in some situations. I see some of caveats in UNHEX approach which will make code a bit more complex than it could be, but it's OK.

Comment: @RamonBakker, I've updated my answer again. Actually, you need no querying table structure because you already have field names in the result.